# VueJS: é possível utilizar uma condição para habilitar um @click?

Tags: vue.js

Eu tenho um botão desabilitado, que depende de outros campos para ficar habilitado:

```
<button class="actAplicarTodosFiltros" disabled="disabled">Aplicar</button>
```

Então eu tenho abas que realizam algumas alterações porém eu queria que o *v-on:click* dessas abas só fossem executados quando o botão aplicar estivesse habilitado.

```
<li v-on:click="executaAlgo"><a href="#">Vendas</a></li>
```

É possivel utilizar algum v-if de um botão para o outro?

Comment: Qual é a variável que determina se `.actAplicarTodosFiltros` está desabilitado ou não?

Comment: na verdade são variaveis determinadas com jQuery, ele ficar habilitado não me faz muita diferença no momento, eu estou procurando algo como um preventdefault do v-on:click das tabs, e só ficar habilitado quando ele ficar disabled, não sei se precisaria de uma especie de watch

Comment: _"variaveis determinadas com jQuery"_  - deixa o jQuery! :) Brincadeira, mas se tiveres lógica Vue.js isso é bem mais simples. Assim podias controlar ambas. Vou dar um exemplo.

Comment: Estou para aqui a pensar e custa-me misturar jQuery... são gerações e lógicas diferentes. Podes mostrar o código que muda o `disabled` desse botão?

Comment: é coisa simples, um if em outro botão que quando ele for clicado ele da um $('.actAplicarTodosFiltros').attr('disabled', false);

Comment: E essa parte é 100% descolada do  componente do Vue?

Comment: aham, o disabled não tá entrando em nada do vue, somente o click das tabs

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64015/discussion-between-haykou-and-sergio).

Comment: Alguma das respostas respondeu/resolveu a pergunta?

Comment: @Sergio elas ajudaram sim, mas acabei resolvendo de outra forma

Comment: Ok! Era interessante colocares aqui como resposta para completar a pergunta e soluções

Comment: @Sergio, vou reformular a pergunta e colocar a minha solução, acho que expliquei errado porque a solução foi mais simples do que parecia

Answer (score 1):

Misturar lógica jQuery com Vue.js não é muito simples, e desaconselho. Mas porque é possivel e pode ser mesmo necessário podes usar o `MutationObserver` para detetar mudanças no `button` e importá-las para o Vue. Seria algo assim:

```js
document.querySelector('#toggle').addEventListener('click', function toggle() {
  const button = document.querySelector('#app button');
  button.disabled = !button.disabled;
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      disabled: false
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const button = this.$el.querySelector('button');
    const $this = this;
    new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
        if (mutation.type == "attributes") {
         $this.disabled = button.disabled;
        }
      });
    }).observe(button, {
      attributes: true
    });
  },
  methods: {
    executaAlgo() {
      if (this.disabled) return;
      alert('Clicado!');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
p {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccf;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button class="actAplicarTodosFiltros" :disabled="disabled">Aplicar</button>
  <ul>
    <li v-on:click="executaAlgo"><a href="#">Vendas</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<p id="toggle">Clica aqui para desabilitar o botão sem Vue.js</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

É possível misturar códigos externos sem nenhum problema com instâncias do Vue.js. Veja o exemplo que fiz, criei uma variável chamada `condicao` fora do Vue e associei na instância do Vue. Quando você realiza desta forma, a variável externa é transformada em two-way databind.

Depois de criado o two-way databind, você pode utilizar funções externas para manipular estes dados, inclusive quando ela é alterada o Vue reconhece e altera no componente sem nenhum problema.

Também crie uma função para validar o botão, nela você desabilita ou habilita de acordo com as condições da variável externa.

Segue código:

```js
var condicao = {
  opcao1: false,
  opcao2: false,
  opcao3: false,
};

function habilitarBotaoComFuncaoExterna() {
  condicao.opcao1 = true;
  condicao.opcao2 = true;
  condicao.opcao3 = true;
}

function desabilitarBotaoComFuncaoExterna() {
  condicao.opcao1 = false;
  condicao.opcao2 = false;
  condicao.opcao3 = false;
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    aba: 1,
    condicao: condicao,
  },
  methods: {
    verificaCondicao: function() {
      return !!this.condicao.opcao1 && !!this.condicao.opcao2 && !!this.condicao.opcao3;
    },
    fazAlgumaCoisa: function() {
      console.log('Botão clicado, faz alguma coisa...');
    },
    trocarDeAba: function($event, aba) {
      if (!this.verificaCondicao()) {
        console.log('Habilite opções para prosseguir com a troca de guia.');
        return; // Cancela a ação pois não foi atendida
      }

      // Troca de aba
      this.aba = aba;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="trocarDeAba($event, 1)">Aba 1</a>
      <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="trocarDeAba($event, 2)">Aba 2</a>
      <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="trocarDeAba($event, 3)">Aba 3</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div v-if="aba == 1">Conteúdo Aba 1 ******************</div>
      <div v-if="aba == 2">Conteúdo Aba 2 ------------------</div>
      <div v-if="aba == 3">Conteúdo Aba 3 ##################</div>
    </div>
    <div v-if="verificaCondicao()">
      <h4>Agora você pode clicar nas abas</h4>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <h4>Marque as opções para poder alterar de guia</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div>
    <button v-on:click="fazAlgumaCoisa()" class="actAplicarTodosFiltros" :disabled="!verificaCondicao()">
        Opção com Condições
       </button>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li><input v-model="condicao.opcao1" type="checkbox"> Condição 01</li>
    <li><input v-model="condicao.opcao2" type="checkbox"> Condição 02</li>
    <li><input v-model="condicao.opcao3" type="checkbox"> Condição 03</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <button onClick="habilitarBotaoComFuncaoExterna()">Fora do Vuejs - Habilitar</button>
  <button onClick="desabilitarBotaoComFuncaoExterna()">Fora do Vuejs - Habilitar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: O problema fica bem mais simples com um `input` que permite binding bi-direcional. O problema da pergunta é uma propriedade `disabled` de um botão.

Comment: Alterei o exemplo, acho que agora se encaixou no que ele solicitou. ;)

Comment: Para não haver equivoco: acho a tua resposta boa, verificar cada vez que há clique, apesar de ainda não teres atributo `disabled` como na pergunta. A minha abordagem é manter um valor booleano no `state` do componente. Ambas são válidas e boas respostas :P Vamos ver o que o AP prefere :)

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário @Sergio. Deixei o código com mais coisas para ter como exemplo. Uma forma de não ter que checar toda vez, bastaria mover o "verificaCondicao" para uma propriedade computed, assim teria o cache da mesma e só em caso de troca dos valores que haveria uma outra verificação. Mas, a ideia era deixar de forma simples, sem ter que entrar em cada detalhe do Vue e a resposta ficar muito complexa.

Answer (score 1):

O jeito mais fácil de fazer isso é usando a diretiva `v-bind`.

Exemplo:

```
<v-bind:disabled="(form.nome == '')">
```